# set countdown to only show between monday and wednesday

Tags: javascript

I've currently got a countdown that counts to 11.59 am every day.

However, I need to set it so it counts down to Wednesday 11.59pm every week and only show from Monday.

So on Sunday, Saturday, Friday and Thursday the countdown won't show. I've figured that bit out but can't find a way to set my countdown for every Wednesday at 11.59pm.

I guess it would be done with `getDay()` somehow, but not sure how to put it together.

This is the code I've currently got:

```
var today = new Date(new Date().getTime());
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 10, 59, 59));

function time_remaining(endtime) {
  var t = endtime - new Date();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function run_clock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  if (null === clock) {
    return;
  }
  var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function update_clock() {
    var t = time_remaining(endtime);
    hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    day = today.getDay();
    if ((t.total <= 0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6) || (day === 5) || (day === 4)) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  update_clock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock, 1000);
}
run_clock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getDay()` value to get the current day(`0(Sunday)...6(Saturday)`), then use that to show the calendar and find the dead line

```js
var today = new Date(),
  curDay = today.getDay();
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + 3 - curDay, 10, 59, 59));

//var x = 0;
function time_remaining(endtime) {
  var t = endtime - new Date();
  //var t = endtime - new Date(today).setSeconds(today.getSeconds()+ ++x);
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  //console.log(t, days)
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function run_clock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  if (null === clock) {
    return;
  }
  var days_span = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function update_clock() {
    var t = time_remaining(endtime);
    days_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
    hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    day = today.getDay();
    if ((t.total <= 0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6) || (day === 5) || (day === 4)) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  update_clock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock, 1000);
}
if (curDay > 0 && today < deadline) {
  run_clock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
```

```html
<div id="deadline_Container"></div>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```